# Start colorbox gallery window directly from click on img tag, without hyperlink tag

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I have some image and I want colorbox to start its gallery directly from mouse click on `img` tag, not on a `hyperlink` tag as the rules are. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).colorbox({href: $(this).attr('src')});
});
```

Also see my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5HdQB/

Answer (score 1):

first add a class to your imgs

```
<img src="..." class="myImg"/>

$('.myImg').click(function() {
    $(this).colorbox();
});
```

Comment: Class is not necessary, just extra coding.